# How to upload an image in Windows 8.1 metro application?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

In my metro app, i want to upload an `image`. Actually on `button-click`, a file explorer should be opened and prompt for the image. when user selects any image, I want to show it in `view` using `image` tag and save it on the server side as well. I have following image and button code :

```
 <Border Margin="0,30,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFAAA7A7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="113">
            <Image Height="101" Source="temp.png" Margin="0,-2,0,10"/>
 </Border>
 <AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Label="Upload Image" VerticalAlignment="Center" Icon="Camera" Width="178" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
```

Comment: Your Upload mechanism will depend on what your server side is designed to receive. You will also need to show what you have tried sofar?

Comment: actually i didn't do anything in this regards. just placed the controls and nothing more. Could you tell me how to upload file ? i mean how to show file explorer ... @CathalMF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a FilePicker dialog. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465199) is a good article about it. The following code does:

- open a file picker dialog
- add filters for image types
- saves the image in a StorageFile (an isolated storage for your app - [details](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/06/25/file-handling-with-windows-storage-apis.aspx))

This code is taken from the page:

```
if (rootPage.EnsureUnsnapped())
  {
  FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
  openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
  openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
  openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
  openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
  openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

  StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
  if (file != null)
  {
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
    //OutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked photo: " + file.Name;
  }
  else
  {
    //OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! could you guide me now how to handle that uploaded file on the serve side ? i mean how to upload it on the server side ? @Jan Hommes

Comment: What do you use for server side? When talking about server side, you normally speak about a data service in the back end (WCF Data Service for example or any REST Dataservice). Do you use something like this? Or do you mean your code behind?

Comment: Actually i am new to this environment and don't know much about WA. i got an image's path and now i want to save it on server side .i.e. save it on server's specified path on server's hard ... @Jan Hommes

Comment: You can use any data service that accepts an image on your server. What is your preferred language? Microsoft technology is WCF. But it is very complex. If you want something easy and you are used to javascript, start with node.js.

Comment: i am working with C# and have know-how about javascript. @Jan Hommes